# How can I create URL that expires after some days php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project which need to send a video link to any email.
But this video link will expire after 3 days automatically and video url should not work.
How can I do it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have a dbtable with those links, including a token, an 'expires_at', .. Send the link to a script with the token. In that script find the video url by token, check for date - then redirect to video (or a "sorry, too late" page)

Comment: Well, you can simply add expiration date to your links table and check if this date is bigger than date at the moment when user clicks on link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store the videos Ids along with their creation dateTime in a database, so you can query them in your application layer (PHP).

the structure of your URL you are going to serve could be something like this

```
 domain/videos.php?video_id=123456
```

the database table

```
 -- videos table
 +----------+---------------------------+
 | video_id |    creation_datetime      |
 +----------+---------------------------+
 |  123456  |    2017-07-18 14:21:19    |
 |  123457  |    2017-07-16 11:21:50    | 
 +----------+---------------------------+
```

The php script videos.php

```
<?php 
if(empty($_GET['video_id'])){
    die('no video to show');//TODO: proper msg
}
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$query = "SELECT video_id FROM videos WHERE video_id = ? AND creation_datetime >= ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
!$stmt ? die('error') : "";
//before 3 days
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['video_id'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 3 * 24 * 60* 60));
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows){
    //give the video
}else{
    die('sorry, the video is expired');
}
exit;
```

Now, *depending on the time I write this* `domain/videos.php?video_id=123456` would be served and `domain/videos.php?video_id=123457` is expired